# how to set multiple fields autoincremental with hibernate annotations

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have one table in which there are fields like UUID (unique UUID String) and srNO(serial number) . I want both of that field being generated automatically.How can I achieve same using hibernate annotation.?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `@GeneratedValue` or `@GenericGenerator` annotations are expected to be found on `@Id` fields. (putting them on a non id field won't have any effect - and/or hibernate will complain about invalid mapping).

An alternative solution is to set those values in a method annotated with [`@PrePersist`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/listeners.html) so you won't have to call the `assignUuid()` : hibernate will do it for you just before persisting the entity.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntityWithUUID {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @NaturalId
    private String uuid;

    @PrePersist
    public void assignUuid(){
        uuid = generateUuid();
    } 

    ...
}
```